# Too many arguments in my function - Python

Tags: python, function, dll

I am trying to access my function in a dll and pass by value as integer in it. But I am getting a ValueError as:

```
Procedure probably called with too many arguments (4 bytes in excess)
```

My python .py script is as below:

```
func2.restype = c_int
func2.argtypes = [c_int]
func2(3)
```

...

My actual function in the dll is just a simple function like:

```
int DLLfun2(int argtest) { return argtest + 1; };
```

...

Looks like a simple problem, but I'm guessing I am missing out on something. Kindly help.

Cheers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks weird because integer should be automatically cast, but try with a `func2(c_int(3))`

EDIT : 
According to the [ctypes doc](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#calling-functions), this exception could be raised because of a wrong calling convention (cdecl instead of stdcall). But the function is still called (just a sort of warning :s)

Be sure of you declaration in your dll.

If you load your library with `windll`, it must use stdcall calling convention, otherwise, use the `cdll` module.

Comment: @Nerds.Dont.Swear : take a look to the calling convention you're using (cdecl/stdcall) in your dll as I mentionned in my edit.

Comment: In my case, I am using windll to load my library. How would it be different from the way I am trying to call my function?

Comment: @Nerds.Dont.Swear : try to use cdll to load your library, if the calling convention of your dll is cdecl, it will work better.